# Python - Lists - Formatting as table

Tags: python, python-3.x

I experimented with reading a tab delimited table into a list array.
I used:

```
with open('/home/data.txt') as textFile:
    data = [line.split() for line in textFile]
```

that worked fine

a print gives me this (adding line feeds for readability):

```
[('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'),
 ('A', 1, 2, 3),
 ('B', 4, 5, 6),
 ('C', 11, 22, 33),
 ('D', 44, 55, 66),
 ('E', 1, 2),
 ('F', 1, 2)]
```

for the last two rows the values for Col4 have been null.

Now my problem:
I wanted to simply create a column based list, so I just did a print(zip(*data))
however that then omits column 4 in its entirety ....

```
[('Col1', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'),
 ('Col2', 1, 4, 11, 44, 1, 1),
 ('Col3', 2, 5, 22, 55, 2, 2)]
```

I would want something like:

```
[('Col1', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'),
 ('Col2', 1, 4, 11, 44, 1, 1),
 ('Col3', 2, 5, 22, 55, 2, 2),
 ('Col4', 3, 6, 33, 66)]
```

Any ideas how to handle that?

Thanks!

Comment: Your requested output is not necessarily workable - if the short rows weren't at the very end, your columns would no longer line up due to the missing items.  Instead of ``zip()``, try ``itertools.zip_longest()`` - it pads out short rows with None (or another value specified by a ``fillvalue=`` parameter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on [jasonharper's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42544804/python-lists-formatting-as-table#comment72225394_42544804):

```
import itertools
with open('/home/data.txt') as textFile:
    data = [line.split() for line in textFile]

transposed = list(itertools.zip_longest(*data))
```

Now if you `print(transposed)` you'll get:

`Out[('Col1', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'), ('Col2', 1, 4, 11, 44, 1, 1),('Col3', 2, 5, 22, 55, 2, 2), ('Col4', 3, 6, 33, 66, None, None)]`

If you feed an optional `fillvalue` parameter to `itertools.zip_longest()` you'll get some other filler. `list(itertools.zip_longest(*data, fillvalue='a')` would give you:

`Out[('Col1', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'), ('Col2', 1, 4, 11, 44, 1, 1),('Col3', 2, 5, 22, 55, 2, 2), ('Col4', 3, 6, 33, 66, 'a', 'a')]`

*THAT* said, if you're working with a much larger csv and this is a toy example, you might want to consider using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org), as that will make doing this kind of transpose simpler:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/home/data.txt')
```

... will give you a dataframe object:

```
  Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4
0    A      1      2    3.0
1    B      4      5    6.0
2    C     11     22   33.0
3    D     44     55   66.0
4    E      1      2    NaN
5    F      1      2    NaN
```

`df.transpose()` will then give you:

```
       0   1   2   3    4    5
Col1   A   B   C   D    E    F
Col2   1   4  11  44    1    1
Col3   2   5  22  55    2    2
Col4   3   6  33  66  NaN  NaN
```